# varnish listen on multiple IPv6 address on same interface

Tags: ipv6, varnish

We are using varnish 3.0.3 on CentOS 6.5 64 bit. We have an interface which has multiple IPv6 addresses. Varnish listens well on single IPv6 by configuring the same in /etc/sysconfig/varnish but if I configure more than one IPv6 from the same interface, the varnish daemon fails to start.

We configure address in /etc/sysconfig/varnish like below :
VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=[2401:xxxx:xxxx:1::6],[2401:xxxx:xxxx:1::40]

Which fails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Viral

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `/etc/sysconfig/varnish`; add a new variable `VARNISH_LISTEN_IPv6ADDRESS=` as below:

```
VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1,10.11.72.6
VARNISH_LISTEN_IPv6ADDRESS=[2401:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1]:80, =[2401:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2]:80
```

Change the daemon options as below:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT},${VARNISH_LISTEN_IPv6ADDRESS} \
         -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
         -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
         -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
         -w ${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS},${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS},${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
         -u varnish -g varnish \
         -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
         -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked for me.